# Increase the number of maximum redis arguments in an entry without changing source code and recompiling it for Freeradius Redis module

Tags: redis, freeradius

Me and my team are trying to implement Freeradius to our authentication mechanism with a Redis database utilizing the Redis streams data type.

However i came across with the limitation of maximum Redis arguments of 16 in a single Redis streams entry -128 would be enough for our use case-.

After searching around i found the limitation to reside in the files of the Redis module for Freeradius:

```
#define MAX_REDIS_ARGS                  16
```

The above mentioned argument can be found both in [redis.h (line38)](https://doc.freeradius.org/redis_8h.html#a549a4b07fa96f5037b9e3481b94b6b1c) and [rlm_redis.c (line 40)](https://doc.freeradius.org/rlm__redis_8c.html#a549a4b07fa96f5037b9e3481b94b6b1c).

Although changing the said value and compiling Freeradius from source code would solve the issue does anyone know an easier/ less error prone method to achieve this. Like somehow overwriting this value from a configuration file when using a prepackaged version.

Thank you for any advice or opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The Redis argument limit is hardcoded in the source, but from v3.2.1 it will be raised from 16 to 256. See https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/pull/4535.

Comment: Hi Matthew. Thanks for the answer, which is the exact same one i also received from the support team.
Do you (or does anyone) know when will v3.2.1 be out?

Comment: When I release it :). But unlikely for at least a few months, as 3.2.0 was only released a few weeks ago.